# UILabel shifts to the right when cell is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a UITableView and have cells in it and I am using textLabel and detailTextLabel in it along with a accessoryView which is a disclosureIndicator. These are my constraints.

```
if (cell.contentView.constraints.count == 0) {
      cell.textLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      cell.detailTextLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      let margins = cell.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

      // TextLabel constraints
      cell.textLabel?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.leftAnchor).isActive = true
      cell.textLabel?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

      // DetailTextLabel constraints
      cell.detailTextLabel?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
      cell.detailTextLabel?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (cell.textLabel?.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor)!, constant: 10).isActive = true
      cell.detailTextLabel?.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margins.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Now when the Table View is first loaded I see everything fine i.e `detailTextLabel` is -10 points away from contentView but when I tap the cell the `detailTextLabel` shifts to the right and hugs to the `contentView` as if -10 point constraint isn't even there. Now when I come back to this VC again, I still see `detailTextLabel` hugging to contentView i.e `reloadData` is not taking any effect. But if I dismiss this VC and come back again here my constraint and in place like they should be and the problem comes up again when I tap on the cell to go to the next screen.

I have a reloadData() call in my viewWillAppear which gets called but doesn't produce any effect.

I hope I am able to explain myself, am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: can you try `cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()` in `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: Check how many times are constraints set inside your if statement, once for every row or do they get called multiple times?

Comment: Why do you check if there are zero constraints before setting constraints?  Is there an actual need for this?  Without seeing more code than posted, I’d strongly suspect the if statement is the culprit and removing it would resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using a built in cell type, where the text label and detail label are built in and don’t belong to you. They belong to the cell.  The cell repositions them on selection. You are fighting the cell.

If you want to customize a cell’s appearance and change the position of the cell labels, use a custom cell type, and give it custom labels that belong to you. You can given them constraints right in the storyboard designer. Do not use the built in text label and detail label at all.

Comment: Thanks!! That was indeed the problem. It's fixed now. However while implementing i see a weird issue, when i check the contentView.constraints.count for the 1st time it doesn't give me 0, it should have given me 0 since i haven't added any constraints. I have only 1 cell as of now but could be quite problematic when i have large no.of cells adding constraints everytime isn't good. Is it?? Am i wrong somewhere ?? Thanks!!

Comment: Don’t check any constraints. Read what I said. Configure the cell in the storyboard.

Comment: I am not using storyboard.. I am making UI programmatically

Comment: Ok but then you still don’t check constraints. Just add the subviews and give them constraints or frame, once. If the subviews are already there, don’t add them again.

Comment: Actually i was thinking in terms of more no.of cells say 100 and at any point of time say only 10 cells can be shown. init for my custom cell is called for each visible cell, i add the subviews to my contentView add constraints. But i was forgetting the fact that when user scrolls and say 11th cell comes up but and when dequeueReusableCell gets called in cellForRowAtIndexPath system would try to reuse the dequed cell with everything already setup and init won't be called in this case hence no addition of subviews no more constraint adding. I hope i am thinking correctly? Thanks!!

Comment: Well again, this is why I said design the cell once in xib file and your problems are over. But yes, you are quite right, if you are in init you are guaranteed it’s a totally new cell, not reused.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the constraints of the cell labels if it is not a custom type cell. If you want custom constraints then you should create your own custom cell which inherits from UITableViewCell and set your own constraints.

Comment: Identical to my existing answer.